# Memcached on Windows Failed to ignore SIGHUP: No error failed to daemon() in order to daemonize

Tags: windows, memcached

I'm trying to install memcached from: http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/10/15/Memcached-for-Windows&similar

When I try to run it with the `-d` command line option I get the following error:

```
Failed to ignore SIGHUP: No error
failed to daemon() in order to daemonize
```

When I run it without `-d` it appears to run normally, but I need `-d` to install it as a service...

I've tried the following tutorials but they don't explain how to solve this.

- http://shiki.me/blog/installing-memcached-for-php-5-3-on-windows-7/
- http://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/installing-memcache-on-windows-for-php/
- http://zurmo.org/wiki/installing-memcache-on-windows
- [How to install and use memcached in Windows for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777857/how-to-install-and-use-memcached-in-windows-for-php)

I've tried both the 32 and 64 bit versions but it didn't make a difference.
I also tried the version from: http://code.jellycan.com/files/memcached-1.2.6-win32-bin.zip

Which does not give this error but still doesn't create the service.

Anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 9):

Petesh's answer from the below helped me.

> sc create "Memcached11211" binPath= "C:\memcached\memcached.exe -d
>   runservice -p 11211"  DisplayName= "Memcached11211" start= auto

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18228391/3998308

Comment: So this one command is installing the memcached? Im not sure if i understand it

Comment: It does not install memcached. Once you install you are standing up a service with that command.

Comment: This did not work for me the service started and stopped immediately

Answer (score 3):

I usually run this:

```
c:\memcached\memcached.exe -vv start
```

to have it as verbose as possible.

You could try:

```
schtasks /create /sc onstart /tn memcached /tr "'c:\memcached\memcached.exe' -m 512"
```

as it says [here](https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows).