# Python - Memcached

Tags: python, server, memcached

I followed [this](https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows) tutorial on how to install and use Memcached as a service in windows 8. Then i headed to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732696/memcached-on-windows-failed-to-ignore-sighup-no-error-failed-to-daemon-in-ord) one because i was getting errors. Now memcached is running as a service without problems, i even can connect with Telnet to `127.0.0.1 11211` and a little Telnet windows is opened.

What i am not getting right is what i am supposed to see in this windows. I have this python code to test if Memcached is working but i do not see anything in the telent window:

```
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
mc.set("some_key", "Some value")
value = mc.get("some_key")
mc.set("another_key", 3)
mc.delete("another_key")
mc.set("key", "1")   # note that the key used for incr/decr must be a string.
mc.incr("key")
mc.decr("key")
```

Should i see anything in this telnet window?? Because right now is just a black window with nothing on it

Of course this is the very first time i use memcached.

Thanks in advance for any help that you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type "stats" when you are connected to memcached with telnet. You will then see cache get/set calls and other stats.

Comment: Is there a way to see the key value pairs that are saved in memcached?

Comment: Well, yes. But I guess you could do that with a python lib also.  
Anyway, you can do it with telnet with the following commands:  
Type "stats items".  
You will then get a list with items like this: STAT items:<num>:..... The num is the slabid you will need to use in the next query.  
Type "stats cachedump <num> 0" (If you dont want to see all items change 0 to the number of items you want to get back).  
  
You will get all the keys stored in this slab, like this:  
ITEM <key> [.....]  
  
Then just type get <key> to see the value stored in that key.