# Unable to start memcached on different port on windows

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, memcached

I wanted to start the same memcached server on different ports irresptive of the port i am trying. Now it is starting on default port.
I am using **memcached-1.2.5-win32**

```
    D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin>memcached.exe  -l 127.0.0.1:11213,127.0.0.1:11212 -d start

D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin>netstat -a -n -o | find "112121"

D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin>netstat -a -n -o | find "11212"

D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin>netstat -a -n -o | find "11213"

D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin>netstat -a -n -o | find "11211"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:11211          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12200
  TCP    [::]:11211             [::]:0                 LISTENING       12200
  UDP    0.0.0.0:11211          *:*                                    12200
```

Any help is appreciaed.

**Update -II**

```
D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin>memcached.exe  -p 11213
^C
D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin>netstat -a -n -o | find "11213"

D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin>memcached.exe  -p 11213 -l 0.0.0.0
^C
D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin>
```

But its not starting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally got a way out.

```
    C:\windows\system32>sc create "Memcached11211" binPath= "D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin\memcached.exe -d runservice -p 11211"  DisplayName= "Memcached11211" start= auto
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

C:\windows\system32>
C:\windows\system32>
C:\windows\system32>sc start Memcached11211

SERVICE_NAME: Memcached11211
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 11456
        FLAGS              :

C:\windows\system32>sc create "Memcached11212" binPath= "D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin\memcached.exe -d runservice -p 11212"  DisplayName= "Memcached11212" start= auto
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

C:\windows\system32>sc start Memcached11212

SERVICE_NAME: Memcached11212
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
        PID                : 8056
        FLAGS              :

C:\windows\system32>
```

Got the answer from [How to Use memcached on different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226317/how-to-use-memcached-on-different-port). Thanks to Petesh for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using flag -p to specify port:

-p       TCP port number to listen on (default: 11211)

memcached.exe -p 11213

Comment: Tried , with no luck...I have added the trails to the question.