# How to install Memcached on windows 10 and Xampp

Tags: php, windows, memcached

I have tried to install Memcached on Xampp on a windows 10 machine but failed multiple times.

I have downloaded the relevant memcached.exe for my 64bit amd machine. I've also created the memcached service according to this: [How to Use memcached on different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226317/how-to-use-memcached-on-different-port/18228391#18228391)

I'm just not able to start memcached.

All help appreciated.

Comment: why not to use any virtual environment, like vb / vmware? As far as I know some times ago MS [created posix-layer inside windows-10](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/), and there is working ubuntu exists, maybe there it will be more easier to do.

Comment: I also recommend getting started with VMs. You will probably host this on Linux anyway, so might as well develop on it. Simple start: https://box.scotch.io/

Comment: @Wizard can you elaborate how I can go about installing it? Is there no simple way to install memcached on windows 10?

Comment: @JimL thanks this looks usable but it might have a longer learning curve compared to xampp. Also I have to use older version of php 5.3 and mysql so that it supports my live environment. Does box.scotch come with a php and mysql downgrade too?

Comment: @billbush unfortunately no, I don't use windows-based systems.. sry.. but if you will have an access to bash-shell , you can try to set memcached up as regular install inside any debian-based systems (ubuntu). If it will fail another method is to build it from source.

Comment: Scotch box is just a turn key setup to get started with developing in a VM using virtualbox and Vagrant. You can find others on [vagrant cloud](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utm_source=vagrantcloud.com&vagrantcloud=1), build one using the online gui of [puphpet](https://puphpet.com/) or create your own from scratch

Answer (score 4):

go to http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/3.0.8/windows

and 5.6 Thread Safe (TS) x86

download  php_memcache.dll from above mentioned link & in php.ini use 11211 as default port . restart server

Comment: The question was about Memcached, not Memcache. It is not the same thing, is it?

Comment: Great its help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed steps from [here](http://zurmo.org/wiki/installing-memcache-on-windows) for starting and working with memcached.

For 'dll' file go to 'x86' folder and search for 'ts' as per your PHP version.
You can download dll from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/memcache). Make sure to choose blue flag dll icon for downloading purpose

Comment: The question was about Memcached, not Memcache. It is not the same thing, is it?